# How to retrive encryption passpharase?

Tags: encryption, ecryptfs, passphrase

When installing Ubuntu I chose to encrypt my home drive and after installation update information window came up:

[image]

Where I had to write down encryption passphrase. Well I closed it and it doesn't pop up any more. So the question is where can I find it to write down the passphrase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps:

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open terminal and run following command:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

It will ask for a `Passphrase:`, enter your login password and you'll get the key.

Answer (score 0):

I think you run this:
`ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase`
But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: It is that command, I've just run it and it gave me the same numbers as I wrote down last time.