# Encrypted Home Directory will not generate passphrase

Tags: directory, home-directory, passphrase

When I run the command `ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase`, the passphrase will not appear. I do not know why that is, and I would like some help on this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the full command is as follows:

```
ecryptfs-unwrap-passphrase ~/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase
```

It will prompt you for a Passphrase, enter your logon password.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/293446/how-to-retrive-encryption-passpharase/293460#293460